# route is always invalid

Tags: wordpress, rest

I use wordpress REST api 2.
I registered following route for my plugin.

```
register_rest_route('test-api', '/testRoom', array(

    'methods' => 'GET',

    'callback' => 'one'

));
```

The api:

```
class testRoomPlg
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'registerApiRoutes'));

    }

    public function registerApiRoutes()
    {
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        register_rest_route('test-api', '/testRoom', array(

            'methods' => 'GET',

            'callback' => 'one'

        ));

    }

    public function one()
    {
        var_dump('here');exit;
    }

}

#kick start the plugin here

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'loadAPI');

function loadAPI()
{
    $setup = new testRoomPlg();
}
```

And I'm accessing like this:

http://localhost/testRoom/index.php/wp-json/test-api/testRoom

I found that, while in localhost, need to add index.php before wp-json like this:

http://localhost/testRoom/index.php/wp-json/

But I'm keep getting error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the way I call the callback within class has to be changed to this:
'callback' => array($this, 'one');